# Item_CommonHoverPanel_Actions display template: Click event doesnt fire second time

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, display-template, sharepoint-search

I have added a custom action "Test Link" to item_CommonHoverPanel_Actions display template as shown in figure below:

[image]

Every thing works fine if i hover over Test 1 and Click on "Test link". But if i just hover over Test 1 (Without clicking on "Test link)" and then hover over test 2 and click the "Test Link", it doesn't work. 
Following is the code snippet:

```
 AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function() { 
                if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
                        EnsureScriptFunc('jquery.min.js', null, function() {
                            jQuery(".TestLink").on("click",function(e) {
                                 e.preventDefault();                             
                               alert('clicked');                               
                            });                     
                        });
                }
                else{
                    console.log('Jquery Loaded loaded');
                }               
        });
```

I think the click event got attached to the hover panel that appears first on the page. Does any one have this problem before and know how to solve it?

Comment: The hover is only loaded once, if you hover a second time no additional hover code is run. You need to ensure that your click code and the binding is associated with the appropriate event considering this timing.

Answer (score 0):

Got help from one of my colleague, but here is how we solve it.

```
 AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function() {        
            if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
                    EnsureScriptFunc('jquery.min.js', null, function() {
                        jQuery("#yourtestid" + ctx.CurrentItem.ListItemID).on("click",function(e) {
                            alert(ctx.CurrentItem.ListItemID);
                        });                     
                    });                 
            }
            else{
            jQuery("#yourtestid" + ctx.CurrentItem.ListItemID).on("click",function(e) {

                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log(ctx.CurrentItem.ListItemID);                            
                        alert(ctx.CurrentItem.ListItemID);                                                      

                });
            }               
    });
```